# Golang multidimensional slices into expected output string json

Tags: json, go, slice

In my Go code, I have multidimensional slices of string

```
input := [][]string{
    {"foods", "food by cooking technique", "baked food"},
    {"foods", "food by cooking technique", "baked beans"},
    {"foods", "food by type", "dried food"},
    {"drinks", "hot drinks", "tea"},
    {"drinks", "hot drinks", "herbal tea"},
    {"drinks", "cold drinks", "ice cream drinks"},
}
```

how to convert to json so that the resulting print output is as expected. maybe with recursive

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "foods",
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "food by cooking technique",
            "data": [
              { "name": "baked food" },
              { "name": "baked beans" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "food by type",
            "data": [
              { "name": "dried food" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "drinks",
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "hot drinks",
            "data": [
              { "name": "tea" },
              { "name": "herbal tea" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "cold drinks",
            "data": [
              { "name": "ice cream drinks" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

still haven't come up with an idea regarding this, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not fast, but an understandable approach:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

type mapStruct struct {
    Data map[string]*mapStruct
}

type dataStruct struct {
    Name string        `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Data []*dataStruct `json:"data,omitempty"`
}

func main() {

    input := [][]string{
        {"foods", "food by cooking technique", "baked food"},
        {"foods", "food by cooking technique", "baked beans"},
        {"foods", "food by type", "dried food"},
        {"drinks", "hot drinks", "tea"},
        {"drinks", "hot drinks", "herbal tea"},
        {"drinks", "cold drinks", "ice cream drinks"},
    }

    data := &mapStruct{}

    for _, v := range input {
        temp := data
        for _, vv := range v {
            if temp.Data == nil {
                temp.Data = map[string]*mapStruct{}
            }
            if _, ok := temp.Data[vv]; !ok {
                temp.Data[vv] = &mapStruct{}
            }
            temp = temp.Data[vv]
        }
    }

    output := &dataStruct{}

    fun(output, data)

    bts, err := json.MarshalIndent(output, "", "\t")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    log.Println(string(bts))

}

func fun(d *dataStruct, m *mapStruct) {
    for k, v := range m.Data {
        d.Data = append(d.Data, &dataStruct{})
        d.Data[len(d.Data)-1].Name = k
        fun(d.Data[len(d.Data)-1], v)
    }
}
```

Comment: oke nice.. It looks simple, but for me quite confusing because it has to do loop like recursive while doing data checking. thks for the approach is easy to understand